# Assigning variable to Querytable.TextFileColumnDataTypes

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that imports data from a CSV file into excel using this snippet;

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFileToOpen,_ 
 Destination:=Range(rngFirstCell.Address))
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 9)
```

I would like to assign a variable to the Array(1,1,1,9) part and then utilise it in this code, such like

```
Case 1 
  strMyArray = "Array(1,1,1,9)"
Case 2 
  strMyArray = "(Array(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9)"
```

And therefore;

```
.TextFileColumnDataTypes = strMyArray
```

Is this the correct way?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer;

```
Dim vMyArray As Variant
vMyArray = Array(1, 1, 1, 9)
```

.....
and then;

```
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = vMyArray
```